# In what data format should I export a (lat,long,alt) or (x,y,z) grid to be compatible with the largest number of GIS software?

Tags: raster, data, file-formats, comparison

I am new to GIS and developing an application that generates a 3D grid with (latitude, longitude, elevation) or (x, y, z) metric triplets, and I would like to add an exporting feature that ensures compatibility with the most GIS software.

In case of several possibilities, I'd love to understand the pros and cons considering the current industry standards and also the "efficiency" of the format, as I'd like to reach the largest number of users.

**UPDATE:** I did a bit of homework but I am still a bit lost with the variety of formats. What I have come accross which seem interesting: GRD (Surfer), KML (Google), DXF (AutoCad), WRL (seems cool but not used anymore), SHP (ArcView - closed format?)

Anyone could help me choose?

Comment: Maybe the title is a bit misleading: latitude, longitude, elevation is not 3D (3D grids are voxels).

Comment: Thanks Markus. In fact I could easily transform from (lat,long,alt) to (x,y,z) metric triplets. I updated the title to reflect that, and made the question a bit clearer as well (hopefully).

Comment: I think you need to clarify if you are looking for vector formats as well .. I only ask since you list several vector formats. Vector formats are very different to raster (or grid) formats. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_file_formats) to get an idea of raster vs vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For raster formats, I think the [Esri ASCII Grid format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid#ASCII) is most the commonly supported format across GIS software. Since it is ASCII, it is portable to read anywhere, even in a text editor. Many closed and open-source software (particularly recently developed) generally use GDAL, which has a native [AAIGrid](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AAIGrid) driver.

The two drawbacks are the file size (but it compresses well) and possible loss of data precision, particularly if it is floating point data.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Now my corollary question is: is there any difference between ESRI and the .SHP format from ArcView?

Comment: SHP is a vector format, so it stores lines, polygons, points, etc., not rasters (or grids)

Comment: OK, and how would you define the KML format then? Multi-purpose? KML is so widely used nowadays that it seems like I won't be able to avoid it...

Comment: KML is normally used for vectors, but it can be used for raster images (although I've never done it). I regard KML to be relatively "new" and limited, compared to most other raster formats.

Comment: OK great, and thanks for the link about GIS formats - will take some time to read that. I'll probably accept your post as the answer but would like to leave the question open for a bit more time, just in case someone has another opinion...

Comment: While the ESRI ASCII Grid Format is extremely common, I don't use it nearly as much as a GeoTiff.  This format is my current lingua franca for rasters.

Comment: @SylvesterSneekly I'm 100% with you on GeoTIFF, but unfortunately I've run into too many programs that have either poorly implemented it (e.g. assume it is an RGB image with int bands), or not support it at all.

Comment: Fair point - I've had my share of similar woes, though usually where the program is not primarily about GIS.

Comment: Thank you all, your replies were quite comprehensive and insightful. The Esri ASCII Grid format will be my choice to encode my raster data.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a raster format, a raster being a grid of data. There are lots of raster formats which could do it but *Mike Toews'* suggestion of **Esri ASCII Grid** format is the right one. To extend on his answer the Pro's and Con's:

- Pro's: Plain Text; easily parsable; read by lots of software.
- Con's: None of the "advanced" features: No Indexing, no built-in compression, no pre-generated statistics.

There are other raster grid formats: GRD (as you noted), DEM, SDTS, ESRI Binary grid etc; but ASCII is the way to go as the others aren't read by as much software.

The other formats you've found (SHP, KML, DXF, even WKT) are vector formats so they only store line data and aren't suitable for this application.

Answer (score 0):

I like the concept of WKT

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html

Comment: Thanks, I like the concept as well, but I also need to understand whether or not we are the only ones linking the concept... Is this format widely used/accepted by the GIS industry? My question is precisely about this: I need to choose a format that can be imported in the largest number of **existing** GIS applications.

Comment: .tif, .asc, .xyz.

Comment: I don't believe WKT is suitable for grid data. Their is a proposal though for WKTRaster - http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster/SpecificationWorking01